# How to remove empty <p> tags with Beautiful Soup 4

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a generated html and in some places it has `<p><br/></p>` or `<p>\n\t</p>`,  `<p><strong></strong><strong></strong></p>` like empty tags. I would like to remove them.

```
for tag in soup("strong"):
    if len(tag.get_text(strip=True)) == 0:
         print(tag)
for tag in soup("p"):
    if len(tag.get_text(strip=True)) == 0:
        print(tag)
```

But this finds img tags wrapped inside p tags as it is not considered as inner text of the tag.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is two ways to remove empty tags;

```
for x in soup.find_all():
if len(x.get_text(strip=True)) == 0:
    x.extract()
```

The second way;

```
 [x.decompose() for x in soup.findAll(lambda tag: not tag.contents and not tag.name == 'br' )]
```

Comment: The second way gave me all the `<img>` tags that are wrapped inside p's. 
What I would like to achieve is to keep them.

Comment: `if (len(x.get_text(strip=True)) == 0) and (x.name not in empty_whitelist):`  where `empty_whitelist`  is a list of tags that shouldn't be removed, like ['img', 'br'] etc

Comment: this will remove other tags containing legitimate content, e.g. `<p><img/></p>`